Does Isaiah 7:14 mean that God came down in to the womb of a virgin to be with his people in a spatial sense?
Isaiah 7:14 YLT

Therefore the Lord Himself giveth to you a sign, Lo, the Virgin is conceiving, And is bringing forth a son, And hath called his name Immanuel,

Was Isaiah prophesying that a child named Immanuel would be born during King Ahaz's reign to solve King Ahaz's war problems?
Matthew 1:23 YLT

Lo, the virgin shall conceive, and she shall bring forth a son, and they shall call his name Emmanuel,' which is, being interpreted as 'With us he is God.'

Does "God with us" mean that God came down from heaven to be in the same geographical space as His people?

God was already, 'spatially', among his people Israel, talking to Moses, by a similitude, in the tabernacle, supplying written instructions on engraved stone, providentially overcoming their enemies in war, speaking through chosen prophets. The act of incarnation was clearly for another purpose.

God became man to be one of us, not just with us; and thus, become (temporarily) subject to death.

@NigelJ,  Does "God with us" mean that He has to be spatially with His people? Does God have to occupy the same geographic space as his people so it could be said that He is with His people? There is no space that could contain YHWH as Isaiah 66:1 show, how then could we understand your "God was already, 'spatially', among his people Israel, talking to Moses, by a similitude, in the tabernacle," statement?

@AlexBalilo You have just admitted to the hypostatic union, whether you meant to or not. The Living Person, the 'Life the Eternal'. the 'Spirit' who is 'God'. came down to be among his people, in humanity. I do not 'occupy the same space as' my family in order to be among my family. I cannot understand what you mean. I have my own individual humanity.

@NigelJ. So when the angel said "the Lord is with thee" to Mary was he calling himself God. When Jesus said "he who is not with me is against me" did he mean those who were not physically with him are against him?

I don't understand what you mean. I get the impression that you are mixing up spiritual things with physical things and it is unclear why you are doing that.

@NigelJ. It's your hypostatic union idea that mixes up the spiritual with the physical. You claim to not understand what I mean yet you said I admitted to the hypostatic union.

Yes, indeed. Let us leave it there. We see differently.

I voted to close this question as opinion based.

The OP asks, “Does ‘God with us’ mean that God came down from heaven to be in the same geographical space as His people?”
Although certain inferences can be made from the context of Matthew 1:21-23, neither Isaiah 7:14 nor Matthew 1:23 offer an explicit explanation of the word “with” in the name of the child. Matthew 1:21-23 simply says that the prophecy in Isaiah 7:14 will be fulfilled in the birth of Jesus, the one whom “they shall call” Emmanuel.
Matthew 1:21-23 YLT (emphasis added)

21 and she shall bring forth a son, and thou shalt call
his name Jesus, for he shall save his people from their sins.’
22 And all this hath come to pass, that it may be fulfilled
that was spoken by the Lord through the prophet, saying,
23 ‘Lo, the virgin shall conceive, and she shall bring
forth a son, and they shall call his name Emmanuel,’ which is,
being interpreted ‘With us [he is] God.’

The way Mt 1:23 is phrased and translated in YLT raises an important question: Who are the “they” in the phrase “they shall call”? While the birth of Jesus fulfills the first part of the prophecy, I believe the fulfillment of the latter part as worded in Mt 1:23 is still unfolding – the part that regards the action of a group of people, the “they who will call” him Emmanuel and by that name imply “with us [he is] God.” For them, God did indeed come down from heaven to share "the same geographical space" with his people (cf John 1:14).

It’s a bit odd that Isaiah 7 identifies the woman as the one who will name the child Immanuel, not “they”

@AviAvraham - Yes, the change in referents (of "thou" in Mt 1 :21) and pronouns (from thou to they in Mt 1:23) was what made me start to think of an expanding circle of people.
